# Why is the 'foreign address' not IP address of external computer?

Tags: networking, ssh, network-programming

I am checking the internet connection of my computer and do not understand a few points.

The following is a result from `$ netstat`:

[image]

I do not understand why for some items in the list have  `localhost:xxxxx` as their **foreign address**.

since `netstat` shows the internet connections, shouldn't this show IP addresses of outside my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`netstat` per default tries to convert the data it finds into host names. It does so by reverse resolving the IP addresses via DNS.

For example, `127.0.0.1` gets replaced with `localhost` in this case.

The same happens with the ports, but there it doesn't happen via DNS, but via a file like `/etc/services` which provides a mapping between port numbers and service names.

You can prevent this with the `netstat` option `-n`.